# Sort by in LWC datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have created LWC data-table and there are 10 columns added in this. I have to sort this all columns as per their field data type. Example, 1st columns to sort by name, 2nd date, 3rd by number, 4th by number/Name etc.
So the columns which contains numeric value as well as start text in small letter(a) and capital letter (A) is not working perfectly.

for example, I have a name column where name starts with Blank, number, small letter, capital letter. When I sort this by fieldName (this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName).
Expected result should be - first start with blank, then asc number value then alphabetical values irrespective of case sensitive. It should be like whether letter start with small (c) and capital (D). (c) should come first. But it is not happening. also numeric value not working.

I am pasting piece of code here. Please help me in this!

.js -->

```
    const columns = [
    { 
        label: 'Broker', 
        fieldName: 'BrokerURL' , 
        type: 'url' ,
        sortable: "true", 
        typeAttributes : { 
                    label : {
                        fieldName: 'BrokerName' 
                    },
                    target : '_blank'
                }
    }]

     handleSortdata(event) 
    {
        // field name
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
    
        // sort direction
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    
        // calling sortdata function to sort the data based on direction and selected field
        this.sortData(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirection);
    }

    sortData(fieldname, direction) 
    {
        
        // serialize the data before calling sort function
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.opportunityTable));

        // Return the value stored in the field
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };

        // cheking reverse direction
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;

        // sorting data 
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; // handling null values
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';

            // sorting values based on direction
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });

        // set the sorted data to data table data
        this.opportunityTable = parseData;
}
```

.html -->

```
 <lightning-datatable key-field="id" 
                             data={opportunityTable} 
                             columns={columns}
                             sorted-by={sortBy}
                             sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                             onsort={handleSortdata}>
          enable-infinite-loading
          onloadmore={loadMoreData}>
        </lightning-datatable>
```